# how to create a thread in java in 3rd way

Tags: java, multithreading

all of us know we can create thread in java in 2 ways:

- Extend Thread Class
- Implement Runnable Interface.

Other than these 2 ways we have any other way to implement a **THREAD**?

I have to face this Q in one technical discussion.

Comment: Using JNI and pthreads, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By implementing `Runnable` you don't create a new thread, you just prepare your code for parallel execution.

The actual new thread will always be created by using a `Thread` object.

See [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for further information. (A quote from there: *Notice that both examples invoke `Thread.start` in order to start the new thread.*

Comment: "prepare the code?"  That's a stretch.  Runnable is just an interface.  An object that implements Runnable is guraranteed to have a method called 'void run()'.  That's all it means.  What your program does with that is up to you.  You have to provide a Runnable object if you want to explicitly start a Java Thread, but you don't need a Thread to make use of a Runnable.  (e.g., I could define a class that uses a caller-provided Runnable as a call-back.)

Answer (score 2):

How about using a ThreadPool (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)? You could pack your tasks into it and run them all as threads using a ThreadPoolExecutor (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)? It's an interface similar to Runnable, used for tasks that can be executed by another thread. I am guessing this was an interview question that was trying (awkwardly) to elicit how familiar you were with the `java.util.concurrent` classes.

> @FunctionalInterface 
>   public interface **Callable**
>
> A task that returns a result and may throw an exception. Implementors
>   define a single method with no arguments called `call`.
>
> The Callable interface is similar to Runnable, in that both are
>   designed for classes whose instances are potentially executed by
>   another thread. A Runnable, however, does not return a result and
>   cannot throw a checked exception.
>
> The Executors class contains utility methods to convert from other
>   common forms to Callable classes.
>
> Since:
>       1.5 See Also:
>       Executor

Like ifLoop said, the actual thread will be implemented using a `java.lang.Thread`; Runnable and Callable are mechanisms for separating the logic to be executed from the means of execution.

Answer (score 1):

**No**.    There is no other way. Refer [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) doc.

Comment: Depends on what the question really means.  You are correct in that, every thread in a Java program is managed by a Thread instance, but not every Thread in a program is explicitly created by the application code.  Some Threads may be created deep within Java library calls or 3rd-party library calls.